# Series block connection without copying blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a model with n blocks connected in series (And last (nth) block's outputs are connected to first block inputs). Only difference among them is the parameter's value (first array element in matlab is value for first block's parameter, second value for the second block and so on). How can I implement it without explicitly copying blocks? What I have now:
[image]

I want to have this:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by implicitly copying? You mean how to write a MATLAB script which generates a Simulink model like the one in your original post?

Comment: I can write a MATLAB script which will generate model like one on the first pic. But I am wondering whether it possible not to have all these 6 subsystems (because they are identical) but have just one (second pic) and use it in a manner like on the first pic.